# What is services in Angular? how can i use?

Tags: angularjs

I have create a function and a alert message within the controller and call it in the page.
while pages loads the message alerts twice.

what the angular controller run twice ?

1. app.js
   where i have added the module and js  and call it in the index.html.

```js
angular.module('flapperNews', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
function($scope){
  $scope.test = 'Hello world!';
  $scope.posts = [
  {title: 'post 1', upvotes: 5},
  {title: 'post 2', upvotes: 2},
  {title: 'post 3', upvotes: 15},
  {title: 'post 4', upvotes: 9},
  {title: 'post 5', upvotes: 4}
];

$scope.addPost=function(){ 
  if(!$scope.title ||$scope.title==='')return;
  $scope.posts.push({title: $scope.title
    , upvotes: 0});
  $scope.title='';
}
$scope.incrementUpvotes = function() {
  //post.upvotes += 1;
  alert('dfsakjlkdsjflkdsaj');
};




}])
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title> News</title>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Flapper News</h1>
      </div>    
      {{incrementUpvotes()}}

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could click [edit] and add the relevant part of your code to the question?

Comment: where is the code?? how will we know without code?

Comment: do you use $routeProvider? It may effect in template being rendered twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller doesn't run twice here - you can check by putting `console.log` in the controller function.

What happens here is that Angular calls a watched expression - in your case, `{{incremetUpvotes()}}` on every digest cycle. That's how Angular works, which is why it's extremely important to have your ViewModel-watched functions be very fast and idempotent (i.e. behave the same on every call and not create side-effects, like alerts or upvote increments).

Here's your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fIbrmavjFTzxbXhhuTEF?p=preview) (slightly updated) that illustrates how pressing a button that is not relevant to the `incrementUpvotes()` function, and yet still causes it to be called.

So, only increment an upvote counter in response to an action, like `ng-click`:

```
<div>{{post.upvotes}}</div>
<button ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"> upvote </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon initializing your app angular runs the $digest cycle which binds your values. It actually runs it a minimum of two times and a max of 10, before exiting out. Angular does this to verify that
transitive changes in your model have fully propagated and your model has settled.

--This is why the binding happens twice and the function is called twice.

Comment: While that will work, having a function incrementUpvotes() which has side effects and using a 1 time binding is horrible design IMO and not very 'angular-y'. It's more of a throwback to the old JSP servlet way of doing things.

Comment: I agree, it isn't very angular. I actually don't think one-time binding would solve the issue since it waits for the item to be settled.